# C# Clothing System for Character

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm attempting to create a flexible system for clothing my character in my game. Right now I've got a base class from which all child clothing classes will extend, and additional interfaces to bring which body parts they actually clothe into the equation. Here's my code:

```
public class Clothing
{
    public EClothingBind[] Types;
    public int ID;
    public int Priority;
    public bool HidesUnderlying;
    public AnimatedSpriteMap Graphic;
    public Color Blend = Color.White;

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime) 
    {
        Graphic.Update(gameTime);
    }

    public virtual void Draw(Vector2 position)
    {
        Graphic.Tint = Blend;
        Graphic.Draw(position);
    }
}

public interface IClothingHead { ... }
public interface IClothingChest { ... }
public interface IClothingLegs { ... }
public interface IClothingFeet { ... }
```

Right now this doesn't work well, as the design doesn't really restrict what can implement my IClothing interfaces. Is there a way to restrict interface implementation to certain types? I don't want to turn my interfaces into classes because I'd like an article of clothing, say a robe, to cover the whole body (implementing all four). I'm a bit lost on what's the best way to go about doing this, and all input is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are the specific clothing interfaces adding specific functionality or purely intended as descriptive?

Comment: Can you show how you're planning to use these IClothing objects?  I'm not sure why they need to be distinct types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're setting yourself up for some tough times ahead with this approach.  Sure, a robe covers all, and graphically it will and perhaps affect the "armour" value of the 4 areas.  But implementing it like this looks very cumbersome.  You probably just want a single IClothing interface and have some some identification of where it can be put (e.g: Hands/Feet, etc).  Traditionally, robes are generally a chest-piece, but graphically they cover the entire character.

```
enum PositionType
{
    Head,
    Chest,
    Hand,
    Feet,
    Finger,
    Neck
}


public interface IClothing
{
    PositionType Type { get; }
    // Other things you need IClothing-classed to implement
}
```

I think this might be a better approach rather than trying to fine-tune exactly what body-parts a particular item of clothing does by way of implementing multiple interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

This extends moo-Juice's answer (just not putting it in the comment as formatting is not allowed).

You can have your PositionType have the attribute [Flags] so you can do:

```
[Flags]
enum PositionType
{
    Head,
    Chest,
    Hand,
    Feet,
    Finger,
    Neck
}

Armor robe = new Armor(); //sure why not.
robe.ArmorValue = 125.3;
robe.Appeal = 100;    
robe.PositionType = PositionType.Chest | PositionType.Arms | PositionType.BellyButton;
```

etc.

Comment: +1 from me.  I specifically like the `Appeal` property and might be why I can't get a date in an RPG.  I always thought full daedric armor was hot stuff.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great idea. I didn't know about flags before now =)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than segregating interfaces by class of apparel, it may be more helpful as others have noted to have each piece of apparel indicate something about what it is (headgear, robe, etc.).  While such an approach is usually disfavored in Object Oriented Programming, there probably aren't a whole lot of methods which would be applicable to one type of apparel that couldn't be applied to others (even if, in some cases, the effect may be 'no action').  For example, if there were a method "AnimateResponseToHeadMovement", a "TopHat" might actually do something, while a "LeftSock" would not, but the behavior of the "LeftSock" would still be well-defined.  Note that defining actions rather expansively would allow for situations in which e.g. a person's hat might have to be animated in response to their arm movements because it hung down particularly low.  If the "AnimateResponseToArmMovement" method weren't present in the IHeadWear interface, such response might not be possible.

A bigger issue I suspect is going to be defining the ways in which pieces of clothing should interact.  You may want to define a "CanBeWornInCombinationWith" method which takes a list of clothing and reports whether there are any conflicts.  It might also be possible to define a list of 'resources' required by each piece of clothing, and confirm that there are enough 'resources' to wear all the requested clothing.  Note that this approach may be somewhat complicated if some clothes are pickier about what resources they require than others (e.g. some can only be worn on the right hand, while others can be worn on either).  Even defining an interface that would allow clothing to figure out whether a combination could be worn would be a challenge.

Before it's possible to design an interface, I'd suggest that you figure out what you're really trying to do; how versatile do you need to be in allowing interactions between clothing types, and what functions should the clothes have.